# Generate archetype using ant build file

Tags: ant, maven-3

I am trying to write an ant build file which I want to generate the archetype from a remote repository.

How this can be achieved. I have read the ant tasks for maven and all it talks is about dependencies and installing deploying etc. How can we generate the archetype to our local machine from the remote repository.

Comment: What's the purpose of that? Why not using Maven for that cause it's intended for that?

Comment: Actually I want to write an ant script which will incorporate all the functionality in intself. I mean, it will generate the archetype, add it in a svn repository and using that ant file itself I would be able to compile and deploy my project.

Comment: It sound you don't like to create an archetype in the sense of Maven you want to create more like a project template...If you really want to create an archetype in the sense of Maven you should take a deep look into how it is done in Maven...

Comment: Yeah.. I actually wanted to create a template which can take values from a property file of various parameters and using build will do all the stuff from (sub)versioning to deployment. Thanks btw for your help. :)